# How to display total expense for each/selected month?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I want to display the total expense of each/selected month below the calendar.

I stored the expense total in database like this:

```
  public double getTotal(String email, int month) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    int total;

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT SUM( Amount ) as Amount FROM " + "UserExpenses" +  " WHERE " + KEY_MONTH + "=" + month + "",null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

         total = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("Amount"));// get final total
         return total;
    }
    else
        total = -1;
    cursor.close();
    return 0;
}
```

I'm getting the total expense of selected month only even when I'm scrolling the month

```
 Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);

        totalExpense = dataBaseHelper.getTotal(email, month);

        expense = findViewById(R.id.expense);
        expense.setText(String.valueOf(totalExpense));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can run a query that uses the [sum(x)](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html#sumunc) function on the data that as been grouped using the GROUP BY clause.

- where x represents a column name.

The sum(x) fundtion is an aggregate function that returns the result of adding column x that is it will act on a group of rows as determined by the GROUP BY clause.

The GROUP BY clause should group according to the year and month.

As such the SQL would be along the lines of

```
SELECT  sum(your_amount_column), your_year_column, your_month_column FROM your_table GROUP BY your_email_column,your_year_column, your_month_column;
```

As you want a selection as per *each/selected month below the calendar.* then the WHERE clause should also allow for selection. The selection is complicated by storing the date as separate entities (i.e. year month and day are individual columns). So to select a range of dates (assuming for jan **1** is stored, for feb 2 is stored etc) then issues arise as 20192 (feb 2019) is greater than 201912 (sort wise if simply concatenating) so some manipulation is required e.g. by multiplying the year by 100 and adding.

As such to select a date range the WHERE clause using a BETWEEN clause could be used something along the lines of :-

```
WHERE (year * 100) + month BETWEEN ((start_year * 100) + start_month) AND ((end_year * 100) + end_month)
```

- The above assumes for all email accounts (there will be separate rows/sums per email account). For a single email account a WHERE clause would be added.

## SQL Example

Consider the following :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS user_balance;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  user_balance (email TEXT, amount REAL, description TEXT, year INTEGER, month INTEGER, day INTEGER, created_at TEXT);
INSERT INTO user_balance VALUES
    ('Fred',5.50,'blah',2019,01,01,'2019-01-01 10:30'),
    ('Fred',10.50,'blah',2019,01,02,'2019-01-01 10:30'),
    ('Fred',15.50,'blah',2019,01,13,'2019-01-01 10:30'),
    ('Fred',20.50,'blah',2019,02,04,'2019-01-01 10:30'),
    ('Fred',25.50,'blah',2019,02,05,'2019-01-01 10:30'),
    
    ('Mary',145.25,'blah',2019,01,01,'2019-01-01 10:30'),
    ('Mary',145.25,'blah',2019,01,02,'2019-01-01 10:30'),
    ('Mary',145.25,'blah',2019,01,13,'2019-01-01 10:30'),
    ('Mary',145.25,'blah',2019,02,04,'2019-01-01 10:30'),
    ('Mary',145.25,'blah',2019,02,05,'2019-01-01 10:30'),
    
    ('Joan',345.25,'blah',2019,01,01,'2019-01-01 10:30'),
    ('Joan',345.25,'blah',2019,01,02,'2019-01-01 10:30'),
    ('Joan',345.25,'blah',2019,01,13,'2019-01-01 10:30'),
    ('Joan',345.25,'blah',2019,02,04,'2019-01-01 10:30'),
    ('Joan',345.25,'blah',2019,02,05,'2019-01-01 10:30'),
    
    ('Fred',45.25,'blah',2018,01,01,'2019-01-01 10:30'),
    ('Fred',45.25,'blah',2018,01,02,'2019-01-01 10:30'),
    ('Fred',45.25,'blah',2018,01,13,'2019-01-01 10:30'),
    ('Fred',45.25,'blah',2018,02,04,'2019-01-01 10:30'),
    ('Fred',45.25,'blah',2018,02,05,'2019-01-01 10:30'),
    
    ('Mary',145.25,'blah',2018,01,01,'2019-01-01 10:30'),
    ('Mary',145.25,'blah',2018,01,02,'2019-01-01 10:30'),
    ('Mary',145.25,'blah',2018,01,13,'2019-01-01 10:30'),
    ('Mary',145.25,'blah',2018,02,04,'2019-01-01 10:30'),
    ('Mary',145.25,'blah',2018,02,05,'2019-01-01 10:30'),
    
    ('Joan',345.25,'blah',2018,01,01,'2019-01-01 10:30'),
    ('Joan',345.25,'blah',2018,01,02,'2019-01-01 10:30'),
    ('Joan',345.25,'blah',2018,01,13,'2019-01-01 10:30'),
    ('Joan',345.25,'blah',2018,02,04,'2019-01-01 10:30'),
    ('Joan',345.25,'blah',2018,02,05,'2019-01-01 10:30')
;
SELECT email, sum(amount) AS balance, year, month 
    FROM user_balance 
    WHERE 
        ((year * 100) + month) BETWEEN ((2018 * 100) + 09) AND ((2019 * 100) + 09)  
    GROUP BY email,year,month ;
SELECT email, sum(amount) AS balance, year, month 
    FROM user_balance 
    WHERE 
        ((year * 100) + month) BETWEEN ((2018 * 100) + 09) AND ((2019 * 100) + 09)  
        and email = 'Mary' 
    GROUP BY email,year,month;
```

This

1. DROPs and CREATEs the user_balance table (for the convenience of runnng/testing/changing) the example.
2. Adds some testing data for 3 emails/users each having data for 2 months for 2 years.
3. Selects the sum of the income (amount) for each month for all emails/user for the dates in the range of Sep 2018 (2018 09) - Sep 2019 (2019 09).
4. As above but for a specific email/user.

The two results are :-

[image]

and

[image]

## 4 Android (Java)

For use with Android and uisng the SQLiteDatabase [**query**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#query(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method to return a Cursor you could then use something along the lines of :-

```
public Cursor getUserBalance(String email, int start_year, int start_month, int end_year, int end_month) {
    String[] columns = new String[]{
            KEY_EMAIL,
            "sum(" + KEY_AMOUTNT + ") AS balance",
            KEY_YEAR,
            KEY_MONTH
    };
    String whereclause = "((year * 100) + month) BETWEEN ((? * 100) + ?) AND ((? * 100) + ?)  and email = ?";
    String[] whereargs = new String[]{
            String.valueOf(start_year),
            String.valueOf(start_month),
            String.valueOf(end_year),
            String.valueOf(end_month),
            email
    };
    String groupbyclause = KEY_EMAIL + "," + KEY_YEAR + "," + KEY_MONTH;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    return db.query(TABLE_USER_BALANCE,columns,whereclause,whereargs,groupbyclause,null,null);
}
```

- **NOTE** the above is in-principle code, it has not been tested or run and may therefore contain errors.
- Considering the following, you may wish to name this method to be more descriptive e.g. perhaps `getUserBalanceAsCursor` (obviously the following would then be changed accordingly).

The above doesn't actually return the balance for a specific user/month but may prove useful for other scenarios. To return the balance (assuming double) then the following method utilises the previous method to do this for a specific month :-

```
public double getUserBalance(String email, int year, int month) {
    double rv = 0.0;
    Cursor csr = getUserBalance(email,year,month,year,month);
    if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
        rv = csr.getDouble(csr.getColumnIndex("balance"));
    }
    csr.close();
    return rv;
}
```

- **NOTE** the above is in-principle code, it has not been tested or run and may therefore contain errors.

Comment: Thanks you so much. As I was getting error with your return code so  I've added my updated code  in the above question. Please go through that. @MikeT

Comment: @SsssZ You are using the **wrong getUserBalance** method. The one with 5 parameters returns a Cursor. The one that returns the balance as a double has 3 parameters email, year and month. As per *The above doesn't actually return the balance for a specific user/month but may prove useful for other scenarios. To return the balance (assuming double) then the **following method** utilises the previous method to do this for a specific month*. You can always rename the methods with more appropriate names.